# On a test report (SGS or similar), what does the following mean: 非会员水印

Tags: translation

What does 非会员水印 mean when written on a test report (seems to be some sort of watermark?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 非: not
- 会员: member (especially paid member)
- 水印: watermark

It means what you read is generated from a service that will put a watermark on the result if the service is used unpaid.